# React Native - unable to separate components and containers with index.js file - reexport modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm refactoring and trying to separate my components and containers in separate directories. I'm following the [pattern Tyler McGinnis uses](https://github.com/ReactjsProgram/React-Native-Curriculum/tree/solution/app).

I'd like to be able to import a component like this:

`import { CardReplacement } from './Containers'`

so I am exporting all my components in the appropriate index.js 
You can see the directory make up here:

[image]

I'm also using `export default` in my components that I'm exporting in the index.js file.

However I'm getting errors like this:

> "Unexpected token, expected { (1:7)"

[image]

Any ideas? I've used this pattern before in a React project and it worked fine. Is there something that prevents this in React Native?

On further investigation I noticed this is a babel error and tried to install `babel-preset-react-native-stage-0` but that didn't fix.

Comment: Won't this create circular dependencies if any of your components depend on each other?

Comment: @SimpleJ, Not depend on each other, be able to separate logic and presentation with two directories.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the error message (and possibly the other part of code) as actual text, and not as an image. Search engines cannot index the text in your images so other people will not find your post later if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it this way too:

`export { default as CardReplacement } from './CardReplacement/CardReplacement'`

Comment: Have you seen case where you have to import it and the export it with {}? I don't understand why I would need to export it with {} or import it in the first place.

Comment: If you use export default on the component then it is unnamed. You can't export unnamed components without naming them first. If you use just export (ex: `export class CardReplacement extends Component`) then it should work to just do `export { CardReplacement } from ...` in the index file. But then everywhere else you have to do `import { CardReplacement }` . More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I've never seen this syntax before.

I have to first import it and then export it. I also have to use `{}` around the export:

`import CardReplacement from './CardReplacement/CardReplacement'
 export {CardReplacement}`

To simple use `export CardReplacement from './CardReplacement/CardReplacement`, install `babel-preset-react-native-stage-0`